# Gripper normal to surface

Tags: ros-melodic, moveit

I am using Moveit on Franka Ros demo.

Is there a way to give a special target to a gripper in Moveit like set the  gripper normal to a surface whatever its orientation ?

For now what I know when I specify a goal, I add to specify all the gripper orientation XYZ.

Comment: `specify al the gripper orientation XYZ` - Do you mean: *specify **all** the gripper orientation XYZ*?